# String matching by deleting one characters

Tags: c

I want to compare two strings whether they are exact matching after deleting one character.

(Indexing start at position 0)

E.g

Sting 1: orange

String 2: age

The output should be:

```
The string matches at position 2, after deleting position 3.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code right now:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

void search(char* pat, char* txt) 
{ 
    int M = strlen(pat); 
    int N = strlen(txt);
    int j;
    int position;

    if (M > N)
    {
        printf("No Excat Matching");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        { 
            if (txt[i + j] != pat[j]&&txt[i + j +1] != pat[j])
            { 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == M ) 
            printf("The target string matches staring at position %d after deleting the 
        character at position %d\n",i,position);
    }
}

int main() 
{ 
    char txt[100]; 
    char pat[100]; 
    printf("Enter some text\n");
    gets(txt);
    printf("Enter a string to find\n");
    gets(pat);
    search(pat, txt);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: gets is dangerous and should never be used!

Comment: and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Please clarify the rules? Can you only delete a single character in the entire comparison, or can you delete one character after every matching character?
For example, would "age" and "axgxe" match? Or only "axge"?
Can you delete the character only from one (source) string, or from either?
What is "exact" matching for you? In your example you accept a partial match where the second string is contained in the first.
@Mike: you are right for production code, but this is just a test driver for a function meant to demonstrate a problem so it is perfectly ok to use `gets` for simplicity!

Comment: Only can delete one character form string1 so that string2 presents in string1. E.g rage presents in orange after deleting char 'n'

Comment: Problem with my code now is when I enter string1 as 'chocolate' and string2 as 'co'. The output is "string matches at position 0, 2 and 3". Also, I want to print the position where the character should be deleted

Comment: So wait, you want to find all matches, if there are more than one?

Comment: I just want to find the first match

Comment: You might be able to do that by computing the minimum edit distance between the two words. If the min edit distance is 1 then you know that deleting a character will make the two strings match (using a cost of 2 for the substitution)
To find which character just backtrack.
[Minimum edit distance on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

Answer (score 0):

First off try using good names for fields and methods so it is easyer to read your code for other people and yourself in the future. 
Per Example you could name your two parameters `comparisonString` and `searchedString`.

About your code, your length comparison is good.

For the second part i would try using just one `for`. In which you iterate over your comparison string.

In this for you should first try to find your first char.

As soon as you have found this char you need to check if the other chars are also the ones your string contains.

If not save the first unmatching char and as soon as you have two unmatching chars stop iterationg and return the function. If needed print an errormessage first.

```
int numChar = 0;
int numUnmatchingChar = 0;
int firstMatchPos = -1;
int unmatchingCharPos = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < comparisonString; i++)
{
    if(comparisonString[i] == searchedString[numChar])
    {
        if(numChar + 1 < M)
        {
            numChar++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        if(firstMatchPos == -1)
        {
            firstMatchPos = i;
        }
    }
    else if(firstMatchPos != -1)
    {
        if(unmatchingCharPos == -1)
        {
            unmatchingCharPos = i;
        }
        else
        {
            firstMatchPos = -1;
            numChar = 0;
            unmatchingCharPos = -1;
        }
    }
}

if(firstMatchPos != -1)
{
    if(unmatchingCharPos != -1)
    {
        printf("The target string matches staring at position %d after deleting the 
            character at position %d\n",firstMatchPos,unmatchingCharPos);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The target string matches staring at position %d);
    }

}
```

This should do the trick. But you would only be able to find one occurance.

Comment: In think you have an error in you algorithm:
Let say your searched string is "abcapple" and you are searching for "apple".
You algorithm will see the first "a" as a match, but then return without a match after "c", and will miss the match to "apple" at the end completely.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now I can find the first occurrence. But how can I find the position of the character should be deleted?

Comment: @Jimmyy this value should be saved in unmatchingCharPos

Comment: @Backs close, but you forgot to reset the search position.
When you detect that the match is a false positive, you need to continue searching from the position immediately after the first matched letter.
Example: searchedString = "hihome" searching for "home".
Your algorithm will match the first "h", but will fail when it tries to match the "o" to the second "h". It will then continue the search from the "o" in the searched string, but trying to match it to "h" an so it will never find "home".

Comment: @LevM. true, i fixed that also hope it works now :D thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I remade my answer after I discovered that this question had a C tag.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool foundWord(char *stringToLookIn, char *stringToLookFor, int *matchingPosition)
{
    char *found = strstr(stringToLookIn, stringToLookFor);

    if(found != NULL)
    {
        *matchingPosition = found;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char stringToLookIn[100];
    char stringToFind[100];
    uint32_t matchingPosition;

    printf("First string \n");
    gets(stringToLookIn);

    printf("Second string \n");
    gets(stringToFind);

    if(foundWord(stringToLookIn, stringToFind, &matchingPosition))
    {
        printf("String found in position %d, without deleting anything \n", 
                    matchingPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stringToLookIn); i++)
        {
            char copyOfString[100];
            memcpy(copyOfString, stringToLookIn, sizeof(copyOfString));

            memmove(&copyOfString[i], &copyOfString[i + 1], strlen(copyOfString) - i);

            if(foundWord(copyOfString, stringToFind, &matchingPosition))
            {
                matchingPosition = ((uint32_t)matchingPosition - (uint32_t)(copyOfString));
                printf("String found in position %d, after deleting position %d \n", 
                    matchingPosition, i);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Reached end \n");
    while(1);
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking for a solution in c.

Comment: I won't downvote your answer as it is technically correct, but please note that it is horribly inefficient and also causing the user to be stuck int the program for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

@Solomon: First of all, it is not very safe to read the user input using `gets` as it can lead to **buffer overflow**. Use `fgets` instead. Second, below is a possible solution to your problem (using `fgets`):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void search(char *pat, char *txt)
{
    int M = strlen(pat);
    int N = strlen(txt);
    char match[N]; // character array to record all possible matches
    int pos[N];    // integer array to record all position: pos[0] is the match pos
    int c = 0;     // for indexing "match" array

    if( M > N){
         printf("No Exact Matching.\n");
         return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < M; i++){// loop throug every character in "pat"
        for(int k=0; k < N; k++){ // for each character in 'txt'
            if((pat[i] - txt[k]) == 0){// if a character macthes
                match[c] = txt[k];
                pos[c] = k;
                ++c;
            }
        }
    }
    match[c] = '\0';
    if( (strlen(match) == strlen(pat)) && (strcmp(match, pat) == 0)){
        int ndelete = strlen(txt) - strlen(pat);
        int p = pos[0];
        printf("The string matches at position %d, after deleting %d\n", p, ndelete);
        return;
    }else{
        printf("No exact matching\n");
    }

}

int main(void){
    const int LENGTH = 100;
    char txt[LENGTH], pat[LENGTH];
    printf("Enter some text:\n>> ");
    fgets(txt, LENGTH-1, stdin);
    printf("Enter a string to find:\n>> ");
    fgets(pat, LENGTH-1, stdin);
    search(pat, txt);
    return 0;
}
```

A test for this code is as follows:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall matcher.c -o a.out
./a.out
Enter some text:
>> orange
Enter a string to find:
>> age
The string matches at position 2, after deleting 3
```

Comment: The code you posted will not compile. as there is an undeclared variable `c1`. Also, `int ndelete = strlen(txt) - strlen(pat);` does not give the index of the character that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score -3):

The standard way to compare two string in c programming is by using strcmp () function. It will return 0 if two string matched while it returns non-zero when the strings is not matched.

For example,

if (strcmp (pat, txt)==0 ) 
{
printf("The target string matches staring at position %d after deleting the character at position %d\n",i,position);
}

Comment: Please note the OP is not asking for a standard comparison, but for special algorithm with unique set of rules. The C standard does not have an existing function for that.